# How to pull in metadata for Standard Picklist Value Sets

Tags: api, metadata, stagename

What is the metadata that controls the ability to read and create custom values for a Standard Picklist such as StageName from the API.

Use case:

As an app user, I would like to pull in all StageName values into my app and also be able to create values for various stages from my app to insert into Salesforce.

Comment: If your ask is regarding under which metadata type does standard picklist comes it is under `StandardValueSet`

Comment: @SaiPraveenKakkirala - you should make this the answer

Comment: @cropredy, I am confused what excatly the ask is about so just posted it as comment. Will add it answer .

Comment: What if the metadata that im pulling from StandardValueSet is completely empty even if the source org has values underneath it

Comment: Did you check the  Name correctly. StageName is stored as "OpportunityStage" in StandardValueSet

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for metadata type for Standard picklist you should retrive it under `StandardValueSet`.

But the API names while retrieving will be little different.

For Example we have to use `OpportunityStage` for Stage Name.

please find the [article](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/standardvalueset_names.htm) in which we have mapping for those

Comment: Yes, and wildcarding (*) is not supported for retrieving StandardValueSet: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_standardvalueset.htm